# How to update my local repo using git pull without pushing

Tags: git, merge, commit, pull

I have a local branch where I haven't done any changes. Then I do

```
git checkout anotherbranch
# Switched to branch 'anotherbranch'
# Your branch is behind 'origin/anotherbranch' by 25 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
# (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

So apparantly I need to pull to get all the latest changes. I do this

```
git pull origin anotherbranch
```

I expect now everything to be in sync, but it isn't because

```
git status
On branch anotherbranch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/anotherbranch' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Is this because the merge part of git pull added another two commits? However these commits does not show when I do git log. Instead on top are two commits made by another author. It feels wrong for me to push his two commits. Actually I don't want to push anything at all but just update my local branch. How can I do this? In case git pull was a mistake how can I revert it without producing alternative realities or other git horrors (I haven't pushed anything, except on another feature branch)

Comment: This is not an answer but might help to diagnose the problem. In a new directory somewhere away from your existing repo, use `git clone` to get a fresh copy of the repo. Then checkout your other branch again. If the problem persists, you know its not anything you have done in your original repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git status
On branch anotherbranch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/anotherbranch' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

It means that you have 2 commits that are not pushed.

As a best practice is good to run

```
git fetch
```

once in a while to get all the server metadata (updated deleted branches, new commits etc)

what is the results of this command:

```
git log --oneline
```

it will show you all the log with the commits so yu can see what is the problem

Comment: Ok, so you and git have the same opinion and are probably right, but I cannot understand how this could be. I have recently cloned the repo and then only added a feature branch with a commit. This feature branch shouldn't affect the output of git status when I am in anotherbranch, should it? When I do
    git log origin/anotherbranch..anotherbranch
it shows two commits with another author. How could they be on my computer but not on the remote repo that I have just cloned?

Comment: only added a feature branch with a commit
when you added the feature branch git merge the 2 branches for you and the result is the 2 commits that you have.
can you paste the output of your "git log --oneline" please so i can see if you have merges

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `git pull` as-is. Use `git pull --ff-only` instead which will not create new local commits. The `--ff-only` instructs that if merge is not possible without creating new local commits, it will show an error message instead so you know you have to check the local history because it differs from the remote repository.

I've used Git for about 10 years for my work and I'm currently thinking that *nobody* should be using `git pull` for anything. It's always better to use `git fetch` and `git merge` separately so you can keep better track what's going on.

And when you do `git merge --ff-only` and it fails, you typically want to see the history and see why your local system has extra commits that you didn't expect to have. I prefer to use `gitk` for this but other frontends do exist, including `git log --online --graph --date-order` if you have nothing else but command line.

For the case in the original question, I'd assume that you've previously done `git pull` which created an accidental extra commit for some reason (I cannot guess the reason after the fact) and then you executed `git pull` again later and it resulted in the situation you're seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so before I do
    git checkout anotherbranch
I need to do 
    git rebase origin/anotherbranch
is nothing wrong with doing this because I was on a private feature branch.

Comment: Could you please improve this answer a bit by adding  a link to some source info or perhaps being a little more clear with your explanation? You could also accept CodeWizards answer if this helped (old I know)